# How to redirect from login page to home page if the authentication success in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm checking whether user is authenticated or not from service response, I want to redirect from the login page to the application home page if the authentication success. How can achieve this can anyone please suggest.
Here is the SignIn.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import axios from 'axios'
import { Formik} from 'formik'
import { FormControl } from '@material-ui/core';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function SignIn(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [ssoId, setSsoId] = React.useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = React.useState('');

    const handleSsoIdChange = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();  
      setSsoId(e.target.value);
    }

    const handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();  
      setPassword(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
        <Formik
            initialValues={{ ssoId: '', password: ''}}
            onSubmit={(values, {setSubmitting, resetForm})=>{
                setSubmitting(true);
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    setSsoId(values.ssoId)
                    setPassword(values.password)
                    console.log(ssoId)
                    console.log(password)
                    axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/authentication/${ssoId}/${password}`)
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response.data)
                        if(response.data === 'success'){
                            return <Redirect to='/admin/aboutUs/whatWeDo' />
                        }
                        else{
                            alert("You have entered wrong credentials")
                        }
                    })
                    resetForm();
                    setSubmitting(false)
                },500)
            }}>
        {({ handleSubmit })=>(
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <FormControl  className={classes.form}>
                <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    required
                    fullWidth
                    id="ssoId"
                    label="SSO ID"
                    name="ssoId"
                    autoComplete="sso"
                    autoFocus
                    value= {ssoId}
                    onChange = {handleSsoIdChange}
                />
            </FormControl>
            <FormControl className={classes.form}>
                <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    required
                    fullWidth
                    name="password"
                    label="Password"
                    type="password"
                    id="password"
                    autoComplete="current-password"
                    value= {password}
                    onChange={handlePasswordChange}
                />
            </FormControl>
            <Button
                type="submit"
                fullWidth
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                className={classes.submit}
            >
            Sign In
          </Button>
        </form>
        )}
        </Formik>
      </div>
    </Container>
    );
}
```

and here is the index.js code

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

// core components
import Admin from "layouts/Admin.js";
import SignIn from "layouts/SignIn";

const hist = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hist}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={SignIn} />
      <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
      <Redirect from="/admin" to="/admin/aboutUs/whatWeDo" />
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

When the user authentication success the application route has to be redirected to `/admin/aboutUs/whatWeDo` So what is the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok if you want to redirect to a path that is located in your project you can do that by using this code :

```js
onClick = () => {
  if(checkAuth)
    this.props.history.push('your route');
}
```

and if you want to redirect the user to a path that is not located in your project use this code :

```js
onClick = () => {
  if(checkAuth)
    windows.location.href = 'your route'
}
```

Comment: This is correct in that you should probably use `history.push`. But in OP's code there are no class components so OP's implementation will look a little different. Relevant docs: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory, https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

// core components
import Admin from "layouts/Admin.js";
import SignIn from "layouts/SignIn";

const hist = createBrowserHistory();
const loggedRoutes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={SignIn} />
    <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
    <Redirect from="/admin" to="/admin/aboutUs/whatWeDo" />
  </Switch>
);
const routes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" component={SignIn} />
    <Route path="/login" component={Admin} />
    <Redirect from="/" to="/login" />
  </Switch>
);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hist}>
    {checkIfAuth? loggedRoutes():routes()}
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

The condition checkIFAuth is the login state of your application. Maybe located in Redux or something like that.